# SEO - why my sites images are not showing in google search

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have got SEO suggestion like this:

"Make sure that Googlebot can crawl your JavaScript, CSS and image files by using the [Fetch as Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) feature in Google Webmaster Tools."

So how to know why is my site's static content like images is not crawlable? Also the images are not showing in the google search, why so?

**UPDATE** : As @bybe suggested in the comments, images were crawlable but were not showing in the google search as those were not unique.

Comment: So, have you tried the "Fetch as Google" feature? (There have been several questions like this recently relating to CF?)

Comment: fetch as google says `example.com/index.php` redirected to `www.example.com/index.php` and no html can be seen due to that. I can't find a way to fetch `www.example.com/index.php` as google.

Comment: If your site is at `www.example.com` (ie. on the `www` subdomain) then you should verify and test that, rather than `example.com`. (In fact, you should verify both `example.com` and `www.example.com` in GWT.)

Comment: We have set www.example.com as preferred domain. Is there anything else that needs to be done for that?

Comment: Yes, as I just mentioned, you need to **verify** `www.example.com` in GWT (as well as `example.com`). If your site is at `www.example.com` then you should be testing that, not `example.com` - GWT will see `www.example.com` and `example.com` as entirely different hosts. For instance, if your site is at `www.example.com` then the _index status_ of `example.com` should be negligible (if any). I'm not saying this will necessarily solve your problem with CF, but it relates to your "Fetch as Google" test/comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google should only return image results under Google image search. So if you search for `site:example.com` and click on the image search afterwards, it should just return your results.

Google will index whatever is embedded in the page regardless of whether you're using a CDN or not, and so '*View Image*' will display it on the CDN while '*Visit Page*' will result in visiting the webpage that these images are embedded in.

Comment: that is the expected result but don't know why the images don't come int the "images" section of search while the page url shows in the "web" section

Comment: It's not a sure thing... and takes months compared to normal search rankings.

Comment: but my site is 2 years old..

Comment: and your images are unqine?... can they be found on any other site? Google does not make a habit of indexing images used else where, and yes they have the ability to detect duplicates, even ones with resolution changes and minor adjustments.

Comment: Ok this can be the case as my site is ecommerce one and all the images are of products (provided by brands). I will check more and update here.

Comment: Well that's your problem. Your images are not going to rank if they are not unqine, after all your not offering anything that another 50 or 100 other websites. If you want image rankings then your images need to be indexed before any other website. A good test is, find one of your popular products, download the product image then drag it into Google image search, It'll find all images 'alike' the one you dragged.